# Start Tomcat Server programmatically using PHP

Tags: php, tomcat, exec

I have a situation to start Apache Tomcat server from a php program.
I had tried as shown below:

```
     $las = system('cmd C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\bin\startup.bat',$ret);
     echo $las. $ret;
     //output
     Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. C:\xampp\htdocs\web\operations>C:\xampp\htdocs\web\operations>0
```

But it doesn't work.

Then I tried like this.

```
  echo exec('C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\bin\startup.bat');
```

Output: opening the cmd and closing it immediately with following error.

[image]

How can I make it work.

Answer (score 0):

While I totally question that this is an appropriate solution for whatever underlying problem you're trying to solve (read: Let us know of the underlying problem, and we might come up with a proper solution), here's some tools to help investigating what is going on:

When you start tomcat with startup.bat, *that* process (the startup.bat batchfile) will terminate almost immediately and start tomcat in a separate process (typically opening a separate command line). If that start fails, you might see the command line pop up briefly, display an error message and then disappear before you have a chance to see the error message.

You can start tomcat in the foreground (if only for debugging purposes) by executing `catalina.bat run` - this typically keeps the command line window open and gives you a chance to see any error message.

Now, typically you want to run tomcat rather completely in the background - which on Windows is a service. The way tomcat is meant to operate is: Be available and wait for incoming (http) requests. You typically do this by starting it up at system startup - look up how to run tomcat as a service.

Edit: after you've posted the error message: do you see the path and the error message there? Find out where this path is constructed. Candidates are (in that order):

- any file that you've changed yourself
- Tomcat's bin/setenv.bat (if it exists)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added a snapshot of the error I got. When I run `exec('C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\bin\startup.bat');` its opening the cmd with that error(in snapshot) and closing in a second.